# What is the font used in envato badges (level number)

Tags: fonts

I need this exact font please if you know it, doesn't matter if paid or not.

Update: Sorry for any confusion, the font i'm looking for is used in envato market badges for level numbers check the examples below:

```
http://dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/author_level_13-s-9f1c06d41608d65c7295ac1b131efc37.svg
http://dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/affiliate_level_6-s-d1100327faadf9485508c375df118247.svg
http://dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/author_level_12-s-e950c7783a6576cb67a5d21ffae93249.svg
http://dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/affiliate_level_7-s-53ea2ab29675c3faeb7db71bf85726f0.svg
http://dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/author_level_10-s-74a61b10ea045b3905f06fc92b9bd04c.svg
http://dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/author_level_7-s-bc96ccf3a3109b10c7593dc03d508c13.svg
http://dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/author_level_1-s-fcd269bf7c331e9e531c522485c90e01.svg
http://dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/author_level_11-s-2eea7c437146a16cbb49df77624472ef.svg
http://dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/affiliate_level_3-s-d533d4e4987da4df5bcb847e10bf7e0c.svg
http://dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/affiliate_level_4-s-43802be0772750d1dfe47f357ed7a5fa.svg
http://dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/gold_mo_bro-s-9e92e9809ae30f72616d17562a0d1d21.svg
http://dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/affiliate_level_5-s-1f5dbd9a9bc83335fd2f5f3a44a7ef7e.svg
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Graphics Design! Please read [our requirements for a font identification](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/1083/30216). You can [edit] your question to add what you've tried.

Comment: Thank you for the kind heads up, I have updated the question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be Avenir Next Rounded Bold. WhatTheFont identified it as a close match to Avenir Bold or Avenir Next Bold; the rest is just being aware that Rounded is often an option with grotesque fonts (it closely mimics draftsman's lettering done with a Rapidograph-type pen).

Comment: Closest one till now, also it's enough for me I am tired of looking anyway  TBH, gonna buy it right away, Thanks buddy!